# Field Calculator expression to replace string only if it occurs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I have two fields (`STREET1` & `AKA_STREET_TEST1`).

I'm having a problem creating a simple IF THEN Python statement in the Field Calculator box.  I've been searching the threads for a similar example but to no avail.  Basically the formula would work something like this.

> If STREET1 contains "AVENUE", calculate AKA_STREET_TEST1 to "AVE",
>   ELSE leave it blank

(example below)

[image: database_sample]
Below is my feeble attempt at creating the if-then statement.

[image: FieldCalculator_sample]

Comment: finally what is right answer?
I have exactly this problem....

Answer (score 3):

A couple things to note:

Your code block is currently taking two arguments, but you really only need to take one. `AKA_STREET_TEST1` is the result you want, not something that `Calc()` will consider when calculating. So your expression should be `Calc(!STREET1!)` -- because you want the function `Calc` to do something using the information from field `STREET1`, and that value will then be assigned to `AKA_STREET_TEST1`.

You can use a simple, one-line operation with [Python's `string.replace` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), which essentially incorporates your if-then logic automatically. If `AVENUE` is in the string, it will be replaced with `AVE`. If `AVENUE` isn't there, it returns nothing and should leave the attribute empty.

```
def Calc(value):
    if "AVENUE" in value:
        return value.replace('AVENUE','AVE')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are updating existing field and @radouxju method for populating new field:

```
def Calc(STREET1):
    return STREET1.replace('AVENUE','AVE')
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use the find() function

```
def Calc(street):
    if street.upper().find("AVENUE") >=0:
        return street.upper().replace("AVENUE","AVE")
```

Calc(!street!)

Note that Python is case sensitive, so I  added upper() to take all cases into account

Comment: Find method is not necessary.

Comment: it is, because the OP wants to leave it blank otherwise

Comment: or you need to select first with [street] LIKE 'AVENUE%'

Comment: Correct, if not populating to new field.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've got the right idea but you're testing if STREET1 is perfectly equal to "AVENUE".  Because STREET1 has the road number in it though, it will never be equal.  Therefore, you would need to see if it contains AVENUE, not just is equal to AVENUE.  If you use the python find() function on a string and it doesn't contain the value you're trying to find, it will return a value of -1, so try something like:

```
def Calc(STREET1):
    if STREET1.find("AVENUE") != -1:
        return STREET1.replace("AVENUE","AVE")


Calc(!STREET1!)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def calc(a):
 if "AVENUE" in a:
  return "AVE"

calc (!STREET1!)
```

Comment: This will strip characters after AVENUE (i.e. "AVENUE 131" just becomes "AVE" instead of "AVE 131")

Comment: Agree. Didn't read post carefully

Comment: Its also been flagged for length and content. You'll usually need to provide at least some context around it (maybe an explanation, or caveats on use).

Comment: Agree, my fault. Got distracted